# When/How can I post a link to an open source solution to a problem I find?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

When working with a framework and running into a problem or task that I can't solve, I often search for "I'm using Framework XY, how can I do Z". Often times the first search result is a question on Stack Overflow by someone who had the same problem. Sometimes there is a solution, sometimes there isn't.

Often times when I find the solution myself or with the help of the accepted answer, I package it up as an extension for that framework and publish it on Github.

My question is: How/when would it be acceptable to post a link to my project on Github into that question that I originally found? My theory is that a lot of other people probably also search for "Framework XY how to Z" and they find the Stack Overflow question as one of the first search results, so they would be happy with my readymade solution, right? However, I also don't want to come across as spamming my Github projects all over Stack Overflow...

Comment: I'm not sure you made your point clearly. When I first read "$framework how to XY", I thought you meant something like "what framework can I use to do so-and-so?" However, it later occurred to me that maybe you mean "given that I'm using $framework, then how do I do so-and-so?" If the latter, then you should make that crystal clear because I get the impression that most people read it like I did at first, and that's a big "no no" on SO.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant it in the sense of "I'm using Framework XY, how can I do Z with it?". I clarified it in my question now.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's okay to post a link to your solution as long as you explain a bit about it, disclose that this is your project, and don't go hunting for questions to spam your solution onto. If you naturally find a question you know your project addresses, by all means share it.

Even better would be if you could just post a code snippet that illustrates how to solve the framework's problem, but I understand if you have to use a lot of code to do this it wouldn't make sense to post the entire project code into your answer.

If you are only going to post a link, best make it a comment.

Answer (score -2):

Requests for a framework are off topic on SO, so whenever you come across such a question you should vote/flag that question for closure if its not already closed.

Comment: I don't think OP is referring to asking for a framework, but rather if it's okay to post a project that solves whatever problem in the framework the question is *about*.